# Why XMLElement interface is not part of Web APIs?

Tags: javascript, dom, webapi

In [MDN Web APIs Specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API), there are [HTMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument), [XMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLDocument), [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) interfaces. Therefore I also expected to see an XMLElement interface.

However, XMLElement interface was not seen. Therefore I made this inquiry, to learn why the pattern stopped.

Comment: From a quick glance at the spec, there is only a difference in how they interpret/apply elements within those documents, but the actual APIs and interfaces seem exactly the same, so it appears to be nothing more than a marker to tell the browser what to use. Also, the MDN on XMLDocument is old, short and mentions: "It inherits from the generic Document and does not add any specific methods or properties to it: nevertheless, several algorithms behave differently with the two types of documents."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What specific behavior would you expect from the `XMLElement` interface?

We create new Interfaces only for the elements that do need a specific behavior, and simple XML elements don't have any, they are fully covered by the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) interface.

Regarding your question about `setAttribute`, [in HTML the method](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-setattribute) will look at the name-space in which the element has been defined, and the document where it belongs.

For instance, you can have foreign elements like SVG, in an HTML document which won't have their attributes lower-cased.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 1 1");

console.log("is HTMLDocument", document instanceof HTMLDocument);
console.log("has lower case attribute 'viewbox'", svg.hasAttribute("viewbox"));
console.log("has camel case attribute 'viewBox'", svg.hasAttribute("viewBox"));
```

```html
<svg></svg>
```

*Note that since this <svg> element needs particular behavior, it has its own [SVGSVGElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement) interface.*

Or you can have HTMLElements in an XMLDocument where it won't get lower cased either:

```js
const XML_Doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, "");
const HTML_elem = document.createElement("div");
XML_Doc.append(HTML_elem);
HTML_elem.setAttribute("myAttribute", "");

console.log("is XMLDocument", XML_Doc instanceof XMLDocument);
console.log("is HTMLElement", HTML_elem instanceof HTMLElement);
console.log("has lower case attribute 'myattribute'", HTML_elem.hasAttribute("myattribute"));
console.log("has camel case attribute 'myAttribute'", HTML_elem.hasAttribute("myAttribute"));
```

Having a different interface wouldn't help here.

Also note that the XMLDocument interface exists because it *used* to have some unique method/properties. It doesn't anymore but removing the interface entirely may not be safe for the web, some website probably depend on it.